# How can I render multiple components interpolating JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a website that uses an API from NYT and I am stuck trying to render all the info I have to display necessary info needed (JPG image links, links to the articles, titles to the articles, the dates to the articles).

I have all my info stored in a variable called postNY and retrieved all info(from API) into these arrays:

```
const [postNY, setPostNY] = useState({
    images: [],
    links: [],
    titles: [],
    sections: [],
    dates: [],
    summaries: []
})
// NOTE: OBJARR IS FROM API
// GET IMG
var imgs = []
for (var key in Object.entries(objArr)[3][1]) {
    var obj = Object.entries(objArr)[3][1][key]
    Object.entries(obj['media']).forEach(elem => {
        imgs.push(elem[1]['media-metadata'][2].url)
    }
    )
}

// GET LINKS
var urls = []
Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => urls.push(elem.url))


// GET TITLES
var titles = []
Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => titles.push(elem.title))


// GET SECTION TAG
var sections = []
Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => sections.push(elem.section))


// GET PUBLISHED DATE
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var dates = []
Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => {
    var myDate = new Date(elem.published_date);
    dates.push(myDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options))
})


// GET BRIEF SUMMARIES
var summaries = []
Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => summaries.push(elem.abstract));


// setPostNY
setPostNY({
    images: imgs,
    links: urls,
    titles: titles,
    sections: sections,
    dates: dates,
    summaries: summaries
})
```

Then this is where my problem occurs. I try to render the info like this into JSX:

```
const renderEverything = () => {
    const renderImgs = postNY.images.map((img) => <img src={img}></img>)
    const renderSummaries = postNY.summaries.map((summary) => <p className="desc">{summary}</p>)
    const renderLinks = postNY.links.map((link) => <p>{link}</p>)
    const renderTitles = postNY.titles.map((title) => <h2>{title}</h2>)
    const renderDates = postNY.dates.map((date) => <p>{date}</p>)
    const renderSections = postNY.sections.map((section) => <a href="#">{section}</a>)

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {renderImgs}
            {renderSummaries}
            {renderLinks}
            {renderTitles}
            {renderDates}
            {renderSections}
        </div>
    )
}
```

JSX:

```
return (
        <div className="page-content">
            
            {renderEverything}
            
        </div>
        
    )
```

This returns nothing to the site. I am stuck on how to implement showing ALL these things in the array onto the site. Each array is ordered correctly, what I am trying to display on the site is this(into each of their own containers):

1: postNY.images[0], postNY.links[0], postNY.titles[0], postNY.sections[0], postNY.dates[0], postNY.summaries[0]

2: postNY.images[1], postNY.links[1], postNY.titles[1], postNY.sections[1], postNY.dates[1], postNY.summaries[1]

ETC...

Are there any approaches I can take?

Here is the full code:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import '../PageContent/PageContent.css'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faThumbsUp, faHeart} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'



const PageContent = (props) => {


    const [postNY, setPostNY] = useState({
        images: [],
        links: [],
        titles: [],
        sections: [],
        dates: [],
        summaries: []
    })


    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/viewed/1.json?api-key=uCErKitNpdG7E7ma9rT0IxEGZ4xKs8Vw")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((objArr)=>{

            // GET IMG
            var imgs = []
             for (var key in Object.entries(objArr)[3][1]) {
                var obj = Object.entries(objArr)[3][1][key]
                Object.entries(obj['media']).forEach(elem => 
                {
                    imgs.push(elem[1]['media-metadata'][2].url)
                }
                    ) 
            }
            
             // GET LINKS
            var urls = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => urls.push(elem.url))
            

            // GET TITLES
            var titles = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => titles.push(elem.title))
            

            // GET SECTION TAG
            var sections = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => sections.push(elem.section))
            
            
            // GET PUBLISHED DATE
            var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
            var dates = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => 
               { 
                   var myDate  = new Date(elem.published_date); 
                   dates.push(myDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options))
                }
                )
            

            // GET BRIEF SUMMARIES
            var summaries = []
            Object.entries(objArr)[3][1].forEach(elem => summaries.push(elem.abstract));
            
            setPostNY({
                images: imgs,
                links: urls,
                titles: titles,
                sections: sections,
                dates: dates,
                summaries: summaries
            })
        })
        
        
    })

    const renderEverything = () => {
        const renderImgs = postNY.images.map((img) => <img src={img}></img>)
        const renderSummaries = postNY.summaries.map((summary) => <p className="desc">{summary}</p>)
        const renderLinks = postNY.links.map((link) => <p>{link}</p>)
        const renderTitles = postNY.titles.map((title) => <h2>{title}</h2>)
        const renderDates = postNY.dates.map((date) => <p>{date}</p>)
        const renderSections = postNY.sections.map((section) => <a href="#">{section}</a>)

        return (
            <div className="container">
                {renderImgs}
                {renderSummaries}
                {renderLinks}
                {renderTitles}
                {renderDates}
                {renderSections}
            </div>
        )
    }
        
        
        

        
        
        
    
    

    return (
        <div className="page-content">
            
            {renderEverything}
            
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default PageContent
```

Comment: You are going about this in a strange manner. `useState` is in a functional component then you can't call `setPostNY`. Can you show the full code of the functional component. Where is `renderEverything ` in relation to the `useState` function. is `renderEverything` alongside `const [postNY, setPostNY]` are they in the same functional component.  What is `objArr` where did that come from. can you edit your post so we can understand better what is going on.

Comment: ^^ @MrBrN197 makes a valid point. We need to see the full code. Based on what you are showing though, renderEverything doesn't seem to have access to postNY. If render everything is a function in the render, it needs to be a callBack function and you need to define a dependencies array, passing postNY to it. If the function is not watching dependencies, it will never update those dependency values.

Comment: @MrBrN197 and Jason I have added the full code to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are actually calling the function that returns the content.
you have `{renderEverything}` it should be `{renderEverything()}`

```js
    return (
        <div className="page-content">
            {renderEverything()}
        </div>
    )
```

Also on `useEffect` provide an empty array of dependencies to make it run once otherwise it **will** run continuously.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // your fetch code
}, []) // add this
```

---

just as a note, using `Object.entries` makes the code you are writing quite verbose. javascript has a lot of features that make it easy to iterate objects and Arrays. You don't have to use indexing when you can say the name of the object.
you can convert this

```js
var imgs = []
for (var key in Object.entries(objArr)[3][1]) {
    var obj = Object.entries(objArr)[3][1][key]

    Object.entries(obj['media']).forEach(elem => {
        imgs.push(elem[1]['media-metadata'][2].url)
    })
}
```

to this

```js
let imgs = objArr.results.map( (entry) => entry.media?.[0]?.['media-metadata'][2].url )
```